# Next-Auth returns "QueryFailedError: column User.name does not exist"?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I've got an app with NextJS/Apollo on the frontend, Prisma/GraphQL on the backend and Postgres for my db.

I am trying to incorporate Next-Auth with custom login/register pages, to allow a user to choose to sign in/up either through email and password, or through Google/Facebook/Twitter.

When attempting to log in via one of the social auth buttons, I receive the server error:

```
[next-auth][error][oauth_callback_handler_error]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error QueryFailedError: column User.name does not exist
```

In my database, I have columns for `first_name` and `last_name` because I want to separate out a user's name (and just having "name" is poor UX, imo).

Is there a way to modify my nextAuth config so that I can use first and last name? Or is it hard-coded to look for a "name" column?

Relevant code:
*[...nextAuth].js*

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Providers.Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    Providers.Facebook({
      clientId: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    Providers.Twitter({
      clientId: process.env.TWITTER_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
    newUser: '/',
    signOut: '/login',
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt(token, user, profile, isNewUser) {
      console.log('*************** jwt callbacks');
      console.log({ token });
      console.log({ user });
      console.log({ profile });
      console.log({ isNewUser });
      if (user) {
        token.email = user.email;
        token.password = user.password;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session(session, user) {
      console.log('*************** session callback');
      console.log({ session });
      console.log({ user });

      return session;
    },
    async signIn(user, account, metadata) {
      console.log('*************** signIn callback');
      console.log({ user });
      console.log({ account });
      console.log({ metadata });

      switch (account.provider) {
        case 'facebook':
          console.log('FACEBOOK');
          break;
        case 'google':
          console.log('GOOGLE');
          break;
        case 'twitter':
          console.log('TWITTER');
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    },
  },
  database: {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  },
  session: {
    jwt: true,
  },
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    encryption: true,
    encryptionKey: process.env.JWT_ENCRYPTION_KEY,
  },
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
  log: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
});
```

*schema.prisma*

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model Account {
  id                 Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  compoundId         String    @unique @map(name: "compound_id")
  userId             Int       @map(name: "user_id")
  providerType       String    @map(name: "provider_type")
  providerId         String    @map(name: "provider_id")
  providerAccountId  String    @map(name: "provider_account_id")
  refreshToken       String?   @map(name: "refresh_token")
  accessToken        String?   @map(name: "access_token")
  accessTokenExpires DateTime? @map(name: "access_token_expires")
  createdAt          DateTime  @default(now()) @map(name: "created_at")
  updatedAt          DateTime  @default(now()) @map(name: "updated_at")

  @@index([providerAccountId], name: "providerAccountId")
  @@index([providerId], name: "providerId")
  @@index([userId], name: "userId")
  @@map(name: "accounts")
}

model User {
  id                Int               @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName         String?
  lastName          String?
  password          String
  email             String            @unique
  role              Role              @default(USER)
  avatarUrl         String?
  address1          String?
  address2          String?
  city              String?
  state             String?
  country           String?
  hasOnboarded      Boolean           @default(false)
  createdAt         DateTime          @default(now())
  updatedAt         DateTime          @default(now())

  @@map("users")
}

model Session {
  id           Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  userId       Int      @map(name: "user_id")
  expires      DateTime
  sessionToken String   @unique @map(name: "session_token")
  accessToken  String   @unique @map(name: "access_token")
  createdAt    DateTime @default(now()) @map(name: "created_at")
  updatedAt    DateTime @default(now()) @map(name: "updated_at")

  @@map(name: "sessions")
}

model VerificationRequest {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime
  createdAt  DateTime @default(now()) @map(name: "created_at")
  updatedAt  DateTime @default(now()) @map(name: "updated_at")

  @@map(name: "verification_requests")
}

enum Role {
  USER
  ADMIN
}
```

Comment: Only an idea for a workaround. Why not define a `name` field in your database which concats `firstName` and `lastName`?

Comment: @Gh05d I was debating something along these lines. This scenario would mean that NextAuth would populate the "name" field, and then somewhere I'd have to manually split them and populate first/last name fields which can get tricky with people's names. Honestly I'm debating on scrapping NextAuth altogether and figuring out Passport for my backend instead, NextAuth is just too restrictive.

Comment: I read somewhere in the docs that you can specify your own Provider. So you could clone the Google/Facebook/Twitter ones and modify them. The question is whether it is not easier to go down another route altogether.

Comment: @Gh05d ah that's a good point, I'm pretty sure I read about that as well. Maybe I'll give that a shot first, and if I run in to any roadblocks then just ditch NextAuth in favor of something like Passport. Thanks for the idea!